# SQL group 2 different tables

Tags: sql

I want to link the to table (sum(preco) and name from client)

```
 SELECT SUM(ARTIGO.PRECO) AS SUM_PRECO , CLIENTE.NOME_P
FROM CLIENTE
INNER JOIN ARTIGO
ON ARTIGO.ID IN
    (SELECT ARTIGO_ID FROM PERTENCERV2 WHERE COMPRACLIENTE_ID IN
        (SELECT ID FROM COMPRACLIENTE WHERE CLIENTE_ID IN
           (SELECT ID FROM CLIENTE )))
WHERE CLIENTE.ID IN
    (SELECT CLIENTE_ID FROM COMPRACLIENTE WHERE ID IN
        (SELECT COMPRACLIENTE_ID FROM PERTENCERV2 WHERE ARTIGO_ID IN
            (SELECT ID FROM ARTIGO)))
GROUP BY CLIENTE.NOME_P;
```

but the result of the code above is

```
SUM_PRECO NOME_P              
    39    Joaquim             
    39    José
```

and '39' is the sum off all prices
how can i isolate the account of the 2 clients

[image: i added this image hope it can help understand]

Comment: Please post table structure along ideally with sample data.  There must be an easier way of doing this.

Comment: There's a shortcut between artigo and cliente table?

Comment: @JoeTaras  i.stack.imgur.com/BPTFL.png, this is the way between artigo and cliente

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 
i added this image hope it can help understand [1]: i.stack.imgur.com/BPTFL.png –

Comment: Please write your DBMS

Comment: Because you are newbie, when a answer accomplishes your question, please accept it (clicking on tick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must link `ARTIGO` and `CLIENTE` tables with JOINs, from your image (please for next time put structure table here without image) the query would be the following:

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(a.preco) AS sum_preco , c.nome_p
FROM cliente c
JOIN compracliente cc
    ON c.id = cc.cliente_id
JOIN pertencerv2 p
    ON p.compracliente_id = cc.id
JOIN artigo a
    ON a.id = p.artigo_id
GROUP BY c.nome_p
```

Tell me if it's OK